# Atom white window. How can I solve it?

Tags: atom-editor

I installed the Atom Software when I opened it I saw only white windows :((

Somebody can help me !? [image]

Comment: Pretty tough to tell from what you've got here, but turn off the inspector and go open a file.  And what does "white" have to do with this?  Which OS are you on?

Comment: On Windows 10. I drop the file txt. It isnt working :((

Comment: Well, I would recommend uninstalling it and installing it again. BTW, you should use this StackExchange site only for programming questions, this is not related to programming at all, you should maybe look into Atom's forums and tutorials.

Comment: that looks like a browser-developer console. press F12 to see if it goes away

Answer (score 0):

When you see Atom looking like this, it's usually because something went wrong with Atom loading the stored data from last session. If you click on the `Console` tab, you'll see an error message.

You should take a look at [the Debugging section](http://flight-manual.atom.io/hacking-atom/sections/debugging/) of the Flight Manual. The most likely solution to your problem is to open Atom while clearing the stored data. From the command line, you can use `atom --clear-window-state`, which will wipe out all unsaved files and state data from your previous session.

If you share the error message with us, I will revise this answer to address the specific problem if it's something that I know about.